# Lightning Design Resource, where is the data stored?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, design

Apologies for the elementary question, but I can't seem to find any resource about how data is stored when a user enters a value onto a Lightning Design Resource field.

Here's an example:

```
<design:component label="username">
  <design:attribute name="Username" label="Username" description="Enter the username to show" />
</design:component>
```

If I enter the username and publish my community page, where is the username data saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the application boot up for first time ,your attributes get assigned the values thats there in design file default value.

You need a matching data type and name attribute with design file attribute

```
<design:component label="username">
 <design:attribute name="Username" label="Username" description="Enter the username to show" />
</design:component>
```

Your component file would look like

```
<aura:component access="global">
  <aura:attribute name="username" type="String" access="global" />
</aura:component>
```

Note to use global so that if it is packaged then Subscriber org admin can configure design file

Comment: so, if the admin configures the design file and enters a value. Where does the value get stored? Some table in the database? Sorry, I'm still new to Salesforce.

Comment: Yes internally somewhere where your code and config resides .Inside Metadata .

Answer (score 1):

Data is stored in your aura attributes, for each attribute in your design file, you should add an attribute in your app or cmp file. Here is an example:

```
<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="name" label="Name" default="default" />
</design:component>

<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="name" type="String" access="global" />
</aura:component>
```

Appretiate that names should match. More information here: [Configure Components for Lightning Pages and the Lightning App Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm)